# parameter expansion in file insted of cut

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I wanted to do cut string on last delimiter using  parameter expansion.

```
name='ls $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/drop/abc.jar'
string1="${name%/*}"
string2="${name##*/}"
echo "$string1"
$ echo "$string2"
```

I needed the output `abc.jar`

But I am getting `.jar`

Comment: Are you looking at your `$string2` string? Running the code that you show gives `abc.jar` in `$string2`.

Comment: you already used `string2="${name##*/}"`, so `echo "$string2"` must return the `abc.jar`. how do u see its returning `.jar` only?

Comment: Did you create `$name` by appending `.jar` to some per-existing data, which in turn came from a Windows system, with carriage-returns at the end of each line?  What does `printf '%s\n' "$string2" | od -a` output?

Comment: Is the `name=' ... '` assignment actually intended to be a command substitution? In that case, you are using the wrong quotes (and it would be better to use the `$( ... )` syntax anyway). Also, what is the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` statement intended to mean? That looks like Makefile-syntax for referencing a variable name ...

Answer (score 1):

If you at some point picked up the start of the string in `$name` from a text file created on a Windows system, and then added `.jar` to the end of it, then you have a carriage-return character in-between the `abc` bit of the string and  the final `.jar`.

The `$string2` string that you extract will then contain the characters

```
abc\r.jar
```

where `\r` represents a literal carriage-return character.

When this is outputted by `echo`, the cursor will be returned to the start of the line by the carriage-return, and the final `.jar` will overwrite the initial `abc`, leaving only `.jar` visible.

The solution is to convert whatever file provides the initial filename to Unix text format from  DOS/Windows text format.  This is best done with the `dos2unix` conversion tool.

You may also delete all carriage-return characters in the string using

```
string2=${string2//$'\r'/}
```

in the `bash` shell before outputting its value, or output it with

```
tr -d '\r' <<<"$string2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get "abc.jar" from a valid file name, use the *basename* command:

```
string2=`basename $name`
```

Comment: What is the issue with their current attempt that makes the parameter substitution not work?

Comment: If i am using basename command i am getting the output as ls

Comment: Regarding the notion of using "basename" vs. parameter substitution.  If this was production code, the use of "basename" is a lot more obvious to someone having to support the code.  I had to lookup the parameter substitutions to see what they did.